# Find if symbol exists in parameter of macro

Tags: macros

I wrote the following code to verify if a parameter of a macro is a list of one or more than one fields:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{trace}
%\traceon
%\traceoff

\def\OneTheorem{the theorem }
\def\ManyTheorems{theorems }

\def\LastRef{LastRef}%
\def\PrintTheorem#1{\PrtTheorem#1||LastRef||}%
\def\PrtTheorem#1||#2||{\def\temp{#2}%
\ifx\temp\LastRef%
\OneTheorem
\else%
\ManyTheorems
\fi%
}
\def\Refs#1{\RefList#1||LastRef||}%
\def\TheoremSep{}
\def\RefList#1||{\def\temp{#1}%
\ifx\temp\LastRef%
\else%
\TheoremSep\DoTheoremRef{#1}
\def\TheoremSep{, }
\expandafter\RefList%
\fi%
}
\def\DoTheoremRef#1{\DoRefs#1|:LastTRef|:}%
\def\LastTRef{LastTRef}%
\def\DoRefs#1|:#2|:{\def\tempA{#2}%
\ifx\tempA\LastTRef%
(#1)
\else%
(#1-#2)
\fi%
}
\newenvironment{ProofRefA}[1]{%
{\sc ProofA of \PrintTheorem{#1}
\Refs{#1}
}
}%
{\qed}

\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2|:ab3||ab4||ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}
\end{document}
```

The macro `\PrintTheorem` works as I expect. However, it creates additional output. There is the option to add the line:

```
\expandafter\RefList%
```

however, it will be a recursive call of the macro `\RefList`. I will see few copies of word theorem and the output of macro `\Refs` will disappear. After some searching I found the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{trace}
%\traceon
%\traceoff

\def\OneTheorem{the theorem }
\def\ManyTheorems{theorems }

\def\LastRef{LastRef}%
\def\PrintTheorem#1{\PrtTheorem#1||LastRef||}%
\def\PrtTheorem#1||#2||{\def\temp{#2}%
\ifx\temp\LastRef%
\OneTheorem
\else%
\ManyTheorems
\expandafter\PrtTheorem
\fi%
}
\def\DoNothing#1||
{
\ifx\temp\LastRef%
\else%
\expandafter\DoNothing
\fi%
}
\def\Refs#1{\RefList#1||LastRef||}%
\def\TheoremSep{}
\def\RefList#1||{\def\temp{#1}%
\ifx\temp\LastRef%
\else%
\TheoremSep\DoTheoremRef{#1}
\def\TheoremSep{, }
\expandafter\RefList%
\fi%
}
\def\DoTheoremRef#1{\DoRefs#1|:LastTRef|:}%
\def\LastTRef{LastTRef}%
\def\DoRefs#1|:#2|:{\def\tempA{#2}%
\ifx\tempA\LastTRef%
(#1)
\else%
(#1-#2)
\fi%
}
\newenvironment{ProofRefA}[1]{%
{\sc ProofA of \PrintTheorem{#1}
\Refs{#1}
}
}%
{\qed}

\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2|:ab3||ab4||ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}
\end{document}
```

It works better but I still do not see the output of the macro `\Refs`.

Comment: Sorry, but it's difficult to guess what the expected output is. Can you please add a complete specification?

Comment: Wouldn't `ab1,ab2,ab3-ab4,ab5` be simpler to input?

Comment: @egreg I expect output theorems (ab1), (ab2-ab3), (ab4), (ab5). But I see in output fragments of parameters of macro

Comment: @egreg it does not matter in this case, do I use symbol , or symbol || . Latex code works the same way, I use separator || because in real code I put label of the theorem instead of ab1. Label may have symbol , inside. So I cannot use this symbol as separator

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use `expl3` for the job.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\def\listTheorems#1{\bgroup\ltheorA#1||||}
\def\ltheorA#1||{\ifx^#1^\egroup
   \else \ltheorS({\ltheorB#1::})\expandafter\ltheorA\fi}
\def\ltheorB#1:{\ifx^#1^\else\ltheorD#1\expandafter\ltheorB\fi}
\def\ltheorS{\def\ltheorS{, }}
\def\ltheorD{\def\ltheorD{--}}

\newenvironment{ProofRefA}[1]{%
{\sc ProofA of {\rm \listTheorems{#1}}
}
}%
{\qed}

\begin{document}
\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2:ab3||ab4||ab5}
Text text.
\end{ProofRefA}

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}
Text text.
\end{ProofRefA}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `expl3` for the job.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ProofRefA}{m}
 {
  \textsc{ProofA~of}~\kleyn_proofref:n { #1 }
 }
 {\qed}

\seq_new:N \l__kleyn_proofref_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__kleyn_proofref_out_seq
\tl_new:N \l__kleyn_proofref_range_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kleyn_proofref:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__kleyn_proofref_in_seq { || } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__kleyn_proofref_out_seq \l__kleyn_proofref_in_seq
   {
    (\str_if_in:nnTF {##1} {:} { \__kleyn_proofref_range:n { ##1 } } { ##1 })
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__kleyn_proofref_out_seq { ,~ } 
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kleyn_proofref_range:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__kleyn_proofref_range_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_once:NVn \l__kleyn_proofref_range_tl \c_colon_str { -- }
  \tl_use:N \l__kleyn_proofref_range_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_once:Nnn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2:ab3||ab4||ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}

\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}
\end{ProofRefA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to split the input at `||` and then add parentheses around the items, but with a check whether a colon is inside the item, in which case the colon is replaced by an en-dash. Finally, the massaged items are output separated by “comma and space”.

Comment: the problem of my code that I use the same list of items twice in 2 macro, I call one macro after another. First macro should answer if I have in list only 1 item (and its output is the theorem) or many items (and its output is theorems). Second macro gives output that you show in your test file. I do not have problem if I use only one of these macros. But I see that if first macro uses expandafter (to prevent wrong output) then second macro does not work

Comment: @AleksKleyn Why using two macros when a single one suffices?

Comment: I need to print text (theorem or theorems) before I print list of references. Using \def\Text{theorem} or \gdef of \xdef for some reason does not help because outside of macro I do not see \Text. Also if I use \def\Text I cannot print immediately list of references because \Text should be printed before. So I need to use \@namedef to accumulate list of references. Because I cannot insert macro into \@namedef (this creates error) list created by \@namedef will be the same as original list.

Comment: And only when I print word theorem I any way second time go throw list created by \@namedef to print l list of references. I do not see why I need to recreate list if I have original

Comment: @AleksKleyn I asked you for a specification of what you need. Please add the details to your question.

Comment: I print proof to set of theorems. I have list of labels of these theorems. So I need to print proof of the theorem or proof of theorems depending how much theorems I prove. So I start to see how much theorems I prove (first macro) and then each label in the list I convert into reference

Comment: when I tried to trace code I get respond 
   {changing \temp=macro:->ab2|:ab3}
{into \temp=macro:->ab4||ab5||LastRef}
{\ifx}
{false}
{\expandafter}
{\fi}

~...\DoNothing #1|| -> \def \temp {#1}\ifx \temp \LastRef \else \expandafter \D
oNothing \fi
! Argument of \DoNothing has an extra }.
<     This is not clear why I have suddenly extra }

Comment: @AleksKleyn Sorry, but this is going nowhere. Your code ***doesn't*** work, but you're not helping in understanding what you ***really*** want.

Comment: I got answer, I changed code {\PrintTheorem {#1}}
\Refs{#1} and as result I got output ProofA of theorems
(ab1) , (ab2-ab3) LastTRef—: , (ab4), (ab5)   This is close to what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test for emptiness of a macro argument, then you can test whether an argument contains a specific delimiter (not nested in braces) by appending that delimiter to that argument and then removing from the argument everything to the first occurrence of that delimiter. If you get emptiness, the argument does not contain that delimiter. If you don't get emptiness, the argument does contain at least one instance of that delimiter.

An empty-test can, e.g., be:

```latex
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
```

or

```latex
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\ifcat$\detokenize{#1}$%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \fi
}%
```

If you wish to check whether a macro-argument does not contain `|:` (unless nested between curly braces), you can define

```latex
\newcommand\CheckWhetherNoBarColon[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletobarcolon#1|:}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletobarcolon{\long\def\UD@gobbletobarcolon#1|:{}}%
```

and use this as follows:

```
\CheckWhetherNoBarColon{⟨argument to check⟩}%
                       {⟨tokens in case ⟨argument to check⟩ does not contain |: (unless nested between curly braces)⟩}%
                       {⟨tokens in case ⟨argument to check⟩ does contain |: which is not nested between curly braces⟩}%
```

In your scenario probably nested tail-recursion (iterating on a list of `||`-delimited items whereof in turn each is taken for a list of `|:`-delimited arguments) does the trick:

```latex
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBlank, 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Trim one leading and one trailing space if present.
%%   This is borrrowed from trimspaces.sty v 1.1 2009/09/17 by
%%   Will Robertson/Morten Høgholm.
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\UD@firstoftwo{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UDtrim@spaces[1]{\romannumeral-`\q\UDtrim@trim@\noexpand#1Q Q}%
  \@ifdefinable\UDtrim@trim@{\long\def\UDtrim@trim@#1 Q{\UDtrim@trim@@#1Q}}%
  \@ifdefinable\UDtrim@trim@@{\long\def\UDtrim@trim@@#1Q#2{#1}}%
}{}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletoBarBar{\long\def\UD@gobbletoBarBar#1||{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@keeptoBarBar{\long\def\UD@keeptoBarBar#1||{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletoBarColon{\long\def\UD@gobbletoBarColon#1|:{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@keeptoBarColon{\long\def\UD@keeptoBarColon#1|:{#1}}%
\begingroup
\def\importfrozenrelax#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveFromBarBarTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveFromBarBarTillFrozenrelax##1||##2#1{{##1}||}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveFromBarColonTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveFromBarColonTillFrozenrelax##1|:##2#1{{##1}|:}%
  }%
  %% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArg{<gobble-macro>}%
  %%                             {<keep-macro>}%
  %%                             {<remove-till-frozen-relax-mmacro>}%
  %%                             {<delimiter>}%
  %%                             {<list of delimited arguments>}%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArg[5]{%
    \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgLoop{{{}}##5##4#1}{##1}{##2}{##3}%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\importfrozenrelax
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgLoop[4]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{#2#1}%
  {%
    \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
    \expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral#3#1%
    }%
  }%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgLoop\expandafter{#4#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@barbardelimitedloop{<list gathered so far>}% initialize empty
%                        {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates this time>}% initialize to phrase in case no references are specified
%                        {<separator to prepend in this iteration>}% initialize empty
%                        {<separator to prepend in next iteration>}% initialize to comma
%                        {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates with one element>}% initialize to phrase in case a single reference is specified
%                        {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates with several elements>}% initialize to phrase in case deveral references are specified
%                        {<remaining list>}% initialize to environment's argument
\newcommand\UD@barbardelimitedloop[7]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#7}{#2#1}{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoBarBar#7||}{%
      \UD@barbardelimitedprepend{#7}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoBarBar#7}{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@barbardelimitedprepend
         \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArg{\UD@gobbletoBarBar}{\UD@keeptoBarBar}{\UD@RemoveFromBarBarTillFrozenrelax}{||}{#7}%
         {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
       }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@barbardelimitedprepend[8]{%
  % #1 - <item in this iteration>
  % #2 - <list gathered so far>
  % #3 - <stuff to prepend if loop terminates this time>
  % #4 - <separator to prepend in this iteration>
  % #5 - <separator to prepend in next iteration>
  % #6 - <stuff to prepend if loop terminates with one element>
  % #7 - <stuff to prepend if loop terminates with several elements>
  % #8 - <remaining list>
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
    \UD@barbardelimitedloop{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  }{%
    \UD@barcolondelimitedloop{}%
                             {\UD@nojoinwithbarbardelimitedloop{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
                             {}%
                             {--}%
                             {\UD@joinwithbarbardelimitedloop{#2#4}{#6}{#5}{#5}{#7}}%
                             {\UD@joinwithbarbardelimitedloop{#2#4}{#7}{#5}{#5}{#7}}%
                             {#1}%
  }%
  {#7}{#8}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@joinwithbarbardelimitedloop[6]{\UD@barbardelimitedloop{#1(#6)}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
\newcommand\UD@nojoinwithbarbardelimitedloop[6]{\UD@barbardelimitedloop{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@barcolondelimitedloop{<list gathered so far>}% initialize empty
%                          {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates this time>}%
%                          {<separator to prepend in this iteration>}% initialize empty
%                          {<separator to prepend in next iteration>}% initialiize to --
%                          {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates with one element>}%
%                          {<stuff to prepend if loop terminates with several elements>}%
%                          {<remaining list>}% initialize to current item of ||-list
\newcommand\UD@barcolondelimitedloop[7]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#7}{#2{#1}}{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoBarColon#7|:}{%
      \UD@barcolondelimitedprepend{#7}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoBarColon#7}{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@barcolondelimitedprepend
         \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArg{\UD@gobbletoBarColon}{\UD@keeptoBarColon}{\UD@RemoveFromBarColonTillFrozenrelax}{|:}{#7}%
         {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
       }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@barcolondelimitedprepend[8]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
    \UD@barcolondelimitedloop{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@barcolondelimitedloop\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UDtrim@spaces{#1}}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2#4}%
    }{#6}{#5}{#5}{#7}{#7}{#8}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\PrintTheorem[1]{%
  \UD@barbardelimitedloop{}%
                         {Proof(s) of \UnspecifiedTheorems}%
                         {}%
                         {, }%
                         {Proof of \OneTheorem}%
                         {Proofs of \ManyTheorems}%
                         {#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand*\UnspecifiedTheorems{some unspecified theorem(s) }
\newcommand*\OneTheorem{the theorem }
\newcommand*\ManyTheorems{theorems }

\newenvironment{ProofRefA}[1]{{\sc ProofA/\PrintTheorem{#1}}}{\qed}

\begin{document}

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2|:ab3||ab4||ab5}\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ab1||ab2|:ab3||ab4||ab5}\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ab5}\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3 || ab4 || ab5 }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3 || ab4 || ab5 }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2|: || }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2|: || }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2|:  }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2|:  }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2 || }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{  ab2 || }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab2|:ab3  }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab2|:ab3  }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ |: || || |: || ||  }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ |: || || |: || ||  }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3|:ab4 || ab5 || ab6 }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3|:ab4 || ab5 || ab6 }\end{ProofRefA}
\par\kern\dp\strutbox\hrule\kern\dp\strutbox

\noindent\verb+\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3 || ab4 |: ab5 || ab6 }\end{ProofRefA}+:\\
\begin{ProofRefA}{ ab1 || ab2|:ab3 || ab4 |: ab5 || ab6 }\end{ProofRefA}

\end{document}
```

[image]